# Select unlocked rows oracle

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have an application in C# that uses an Oracle database.
I need a query to fetch the unlocked row from a table in oracle database.
How can I select all unlocked rows?

Is there any 'translator' out there that can translate this T-SQL (MS SQL Server) query to Oracle dialect?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableXY WITH(UPDLOCK, READPAST);
```

I'm a little bit disappointed with Oracle lacking such a feature. They want to make me use AQ or what?

Comment: Oracle and MS SQL Server deal with locking in very different ways. In Oracle there is no Lock Manager, locks do not cascade, and writers do not block readers nor vice versa. You can effectively ignore locking considerations when writing queries such as your example above and your results will be consistent as of the time of execution of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does have this feature, specifically the SKIP LOCKED portion of the [SELECT statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702). To quote:

> SKIP LOCKED is an alternative way to handle a contending transaction
>   that is locking some rows of interest. Specify SKIP LOCKED to instruct
>   the database to attempt to lock the rows specified by the WHERE clause
>   and to skip any rows that are found to be already locked by another
>   transaction.

The documentation goes on to say it's designed for use in multi-consumer queues but this does not mean that you *have* to use it in this environment. Though the documentation says this there is a large caveat. You can't ask for the next N unlocked rows - only the next N rows, of which the unlocked ones will be returned.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM TableXY 
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
   FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

Note that if the table you're selecting from is locked in exclusive mode, i.e. you've already instructed the database not to let *any* other session lock the table you will not get any rows returned until the exclusive lock is released.

Comment: please :Is there a  locked rows for reading that currently updating in oracle

Comment: I'm sorry @hussein_moh, I don't understand what you are saying. This is effectively equivalent to the posted T-SQL code. It gets the first row that is not currently locked and locks it. You can select rows that are locked but you won't be able to do anything with them. Are you trying to get every row that is _currently_ locked?

Comment: @hussein_moh: In Oracle you cannot lock a row from being selected.

Comment: Hi! Ben your post solve my problem, But I also needed the Lock readers to prevent the select of the records that are currently being updated

Comment: Hi  @a_horse_with_no_name why?  In Oracle you cannot lock a row from being selected! And how can i do it?

Comment: @hussein_moh: as I said: you can't. A regular `SELECT` (without `for update`) can ***not*** be blocked. Never.

Comment: Note that the SQL given is not correct. You can't use the "nowait" in combination with "skip locked".

Comment: So it is @rvheddeg; I've fixed it - and added something about the documentation's ridiculous claim that `skip locked` is somehow useful with multiple consumers.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem recently, and after solved it, I wrote this blog entry:

http://nhisawesome.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-lock-first-unlocked-row-in-table.html

Feel free to leave a comment! Your comments are appreciated.

Short summary: instead of select first unlocked one and lock it, I select a bunch of records, then loop through the bunch and **try** to acquire a lock on it using SKIP LOCKED hint. If the selected one is not lockable, move on to the next one, until a lock acquired or none remain.

Answer (score 0):

select for update nowait will error out if you select a row that is locked.  Is that what you want?   I am curious as to what problem you are trying to solve.  Unless you have long-running transactions, the lock on a row would be transient from one moment to the next.

Example:

CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  COL1   NUMBER(10)                             NOT NULL,
  COL2  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)                      NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST_PK ON TEST
(COL1);

ALTER TABLE TEST ADD (
  CONSTRAINT TEST_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (COL1)
  USING INDEX TEST_PK
 );

SQL Session #1:
SQL> insert into test values(1,'1111');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into test values(2,'2222');
1 row created.
SQL> commit;
Commit complete.
SQL> update test set col2='AAAA' where col1=1;
1 row updated.

SQL Session #2: Attempt to read locked row, get error:

SQL> select * from test where col1=1 for update nowait;
select * from test where col1=1 for update nowait
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

Comment: I want to  prevent other users for reading records that currently being updating by anther user