# Pattern to access database from multiple processes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, deployment, windows-services

I have a windows scheduler service written in C# that queries a bunch of records from database, performs a set of operations on the data and updates these records back to the database. I now need this service to be deployed on multiple machines. However, the obvious problem I will end up is the concurrency. The service running on multiple machines should not pick up the same records. Is there a pattern/best practice that fits this situation?
I'm using Oracle 11g database.

We have already reached the maximum limit in terms of performance after using multi threaded approach for processing records. To achieve higher performance, we are thinking of running the service on multiple machines.

Comment: In my opinion you could either use stored procedures which - as soon as executed - mark the corresponding entities as 'in progress' or something else (which must be done locked so another stored procedure call can not interrupt) or by writing a proxy for accessing the databse which handles the multiple access stuff.

Comment: Why would you want to deploy it to multiple machines if it does the same thing? Is there any real benefit to this? From your description, you are causing trouble already :)

Comment: @Markus Safar, I'm thinking in the similar lines you mentioned but just not able to find a best way to lock the status update.

Comment: You can use [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/innodb-locking-reads.html) and [SKIP LOCKED](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14114257/2517719), or else [Advanced Queueing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain the concurrency programmatically.

1. You can have the status column in the table(records) depicting whether the record is already processed or in-process or not processed.
2. You can use the rowversion/timestamp in table(records) in case you want to avoid other transaction updating the same value. (Considering MS-SQL Server family)

Can we know the reason to have services on multiple machines? In case your answer lies for the performance then you can use Task/multithreading etc to achieve the same.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We have already reached the maximum limit after using multi threaded approach for processing records. To achieve higher performance, we are thinking of running the service on multiple machines. Even if we use status column, don't we run into concurrency issues when multiple processes try to update the status column.

Comment: For the concurrency issue, the answer lies in yes and no. Please see the usage of timestamp for the concurrency check AND for locking you can use the transaction with appropriate isolation level. If the table query ratio is too frequent then beware of using high(serializable) isolation level